# Deploying Alexa skill from Codepipeline errors out saying "Not authorized for requested operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to deploy an Alexa skill following the document provided by AWS. I'm using code commit as the source and Alexa skills kit as the deploy for deploying the skill.
I'm getting this error - Not authorized for the requested operation. 
I'm unsure why I get this as the LWA security profile is also set up with the right permissions.

Comment: Check CloudTrail during the time of Deploy action execution for any AccessDenied to get  idea of any missing IAM permission on the CodePipeline service role.

Comment: Alexa skill roles are not managed in IAM as I'm not using Alexa for business

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the generation of refresh token with ask cli version 2.
It's now resolved after using ask cli version 1 to generate the refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

How did you generate a refresh token with ask cli v1, i'm using version 1.7.23, and keep geting erro to authenticate when try to generate the token

Comment: the command to generate the refresh token- 'ask util generate-lwa-tokens' (I used the same ask 1.7.23 version)
Things to consider - Did you properly configure the ask cli and point it to the right AWS profile

Comment: But Yes, i did The same as the version 2, but when i try tô generate the token with this same Command, He ask me for cliente ID and cliente secret. When i confirm, The browser open but with a erro.
(The v2 dont ask for cliente ID and secret tô generate the token) 
Did you configure any Allow URL in the alexa console?

Comment: So v1 asks for client id and client secret, and the v2 doesn't(seems the scope of v2 is not right). So I used v1 gave the right inputs and generated the Refresh token. Just to make sure what is the error you are getting?

Comment: using new versions as 2.6.0, i have the following error on codeDeploy:

Action execution failed
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:

Using version 1.7.23
I have a error when i try to generate the token, ask cli opens the browser, but with an error on the redirect URL
(PS: CodePipeline has admin permissions  )